# How to apply padding to GoogleMap to show all the markers

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm implementing function on my Android app which will read user locations from Firebase database and then add markers on the map for each user.

This is the function which is responsible to do the work. The method also adds the location of the user who is reading the location from the users in the database.

```
public void updateMap(Location location) {
        LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        mMap.clear();
        saveLocationInDatabase(location);

        final ArrayList<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
        markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location")));

        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = dsp.getValue(User.class);
                    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(user.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(user.getLongitude()));
                    markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title(user.fullName + " location")));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i("Info", "" + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (Marker marker : markers) {
            builder.include(marker.getPosition());
        }
         final int padding = 120; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
        mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);


    }
```

What is wrong?

- I added a padding on the map because I want all the markers to be shown on the map.

What I tried to?

- I tried to add `mMap.setPadding(30,30,30,30);` but that doesn't work as well.

So how can't I achieve that. The requirement is  all the markers to be shown on the map.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

- Because I think that If I provide pictures It will be more clear and more people will give me some of their time.
- This is what i want to achieve . [image: I zoomed out here manually].
- This is what i got now. [image]

Comment: have you tried using a higher number? that number is the number of pixels so depending on the screen it might not be noticable

Comment: Yeah I did tried with 
`final int padding = 150;
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);`

Comment: well I mean something like 500 or larger

Comment: Nah that doesn't work as well. I suspect that it only computes Bounds for the last who location.

Comment: Just edited mu question so maybe you'll get clear picture now.

Comment: I would check to see what the actual bounds is being returned from the bounds builder, it perhaps isn't creating the bounds correctly

Comment: I might found the problem and It's seems that Firebase works async and I don't wait for something to returns to bounds are created just for one location. How can I update the code to wait for the query to return something.

Comment: oh well yeah duh, you need to put your code in the onDataChange even where you get all your markers obviously

Comment: yeah I created method which is called when the markers list is initialized and that worked. Thanks a lot.